# Cloud Scheduler has Permission Denied when attempting to run a Cloud Run job

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have created a simple Cloud Run job. I am able to trigger this code via a curl command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" https://sync-<magic>.a.run.app
```

(Obviously <magic> is actually something else)

Cloud Run is configured for Ingress to Allow All Traffic and with Authentication to be required.

I followed this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler

And created a service account, granted it the Cloud Run Invoker Role and then setup an HTTP scheduled job to GET the same URL I tested with CURL. I have Add OIDC Token selected, and I provide the service account created above and the Audience which is the same URL I used with curl.

When I attempt to trigger this job (or when it triggers based of the native cron) it fails with:

```
{ "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "targetType": "HTTP", "jobName": "projects/<project>/locations/<region>/jobs/sync", "url": "https://sync-<magic>.a.run.app/" }
```

Again <project>, <region> and <magic> have real values.

I tried using `service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER updated appropriately as the service account that runs the scheduled job. It has the same error.

Any advice on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Cloud Run. Verify that the service account is bound to the application with the Invoker role.

Comment: Can you check if the Cloud Scheduler SA service account has the role to generate a token on the service account that you put on Cloud Scheduler configuration. The role is `serviceAccountUser`.

Comment: Thanks John, I have validated this and it does not help.

Comment: Guillaume, how do I know which service account is used by Cloud Scheduler?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it looks to me like the Cloud Scheduler SA is service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com. That does not show up in the main IAM or Services screens. Is that what you were thinking I should check?

Comment: I deleted and re-added the service account and magic happened. Not at all sure what happened there as I'm 99% confident I did it the same both times.

Comment: When you have an IAM policy for user A, then delete A and recreate it, the IAM policy won't actually do its job. The IAM policy will seem like it's referring to user A, but under the covers, that's no longer matching the newly created identity. There's a chance this was what's happening.

Comment: To add to @AhmetAlpBalkan comment. A service account has an email and a **Unique ID**. You can delete and recreate a service account with the same email, but the Unique ID will not be the same. Under the covers, it is the Unique ID that identifies the identity.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what i did which **solved** the issue altogether and now I get the ***success*** flag when running a secure Cloud Run service via a Cloud Scheduler job -

1. Create your service on Cloud run - let's call it "hello" and make it secured by removing "*allUsers*" permission from the list of Permissions PRINCIPALS - you should get an error when going to the endpoint as such - Error: Forbidden
   Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.
2. Create an IAM service account for cloud scheduler - let's call it "cloud-scheduler" you will get this: cloud-scheduler@project-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com now comes the important part :
3. Give your SA the ability to **run Scheduler Jobs** by adding the -
   Cloud Run Invoker & Cloud Scheduler Job Runner permissions
4. Create your Cloud scheduler job and add the new SA to it according to google procedure :
   Auth header: Add OIDC token
   Service account: cloud-scheduler@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
   Audience : https://Service.url.from.cloud.run.service/
5. Add to your cloud run service an additional principal that will let your SA access to cloud run invoker

Run your scheduler and voila - all green !
Enjoy

Comment: I does not grant Cloud Scheduler Job Runner permission, and it also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create a new service account, gave it Cloud run invoker role. Disable the Cloud Scheduler API and re-enable it.

The only thing that work for me is changing Auth header from `Add OIDC token` to `None`.
For some reason Cloud Scheduler change `None` back to `Add OIDC token` and Trigger cloud run normally